# dlv debug fail due to undefined object in same package

Tags: go, delve

I filed a bug for this over at the [delve site](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1535).
So, to explain what's going on. I have 2 files in the same package, main.go and common.go. In main.go, it uses some structure from common.go and when i run

`dlv debug --listen=:2345 --headless --api-version=2 --log main.go`

it fails with 'undefined: NewSimpleStruct' and i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Here's what the Go files contain,

```
//main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("HELLO WORLD!")
    segasaturn := NewSimpleStruct("SS", 69)
    segasaturn.WhoAmI()

    fmt.Println("BYE WORLD!")
}


//common.go
package main

import "fmt"

type simpleStruct struct {
    name string
    id   int
}

func NewSimpleStruct(name string, id int) *simpleStruct {
    return &simpleStruct{name, id}
}

func (ss *simpleStruct) WhoAmI() {
    fmt.Printf("name: %s, id: %d\n", ss.name, ss.id)
}
```

Comment: a common error: you also can't `go build main.go` here. You need to do `go build .` or `go build main.go common.go`. Similarly just put all the files or a dot(.) instead of main.go to include all the .go files in the directory

Comment: Ah silly me...i understand now.
@MuhamedKeta your answer is more complete, can you post an answer with that same content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common error, and it's not delve's fault; note that you also can't `go build main.go` here.

You need to do `go build .` or `go build main.go common.go`.

Similarly just put all the files or a dot(.) instead of main.go to include all the .go files in the directory

`dlv debug --listen=:2345 --headless --api-version=2 --log .`

Answer (score 2):

You did not list the second source file `common.go` by name.

So try:

```
dlv debug --listen=:2345 --headless --api-version=2 --log main.go common.go
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thanks for taking time to answer.
However, @MuhamedKeta answer is more complete